# React.js: Rendering Components from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Array of Objects that I'm storing in state with each Object storing values I want to then use to render components:

```
const activeModal = [
    { modalName: 'dashboard', modal: Dashboard, active: true, icon: DashboardIcon, iconColor: 'black', iconBackground: 'white' },
    { modalName: 'memsline', modal: MEMsLine, active: false, icon: MEMsLineIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'mems', modal: MEMsGrid, active: false, icon: MEMsIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'events', modal: Events, active: false, icon: EventIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'people', modal: People, active: false, icon: PeopleIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'places', modal: Places, active: false, icon: PlaceIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'music', modal: Music, active: false, icon: MusicIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'movies', modal: Movies, active: false, icon: MovieIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'tvshows', modal: TVShows, active: false, icon: TVIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'games', modal: Games, active: false, icon: GameIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'settings', modal: UserSettings, active: false, icon: SettingsIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' }
]
```

I am then creating a constant to store the various Components from the Array as follows:

```
const displayButtons = this.state.activeModal.map((item, index) =>
    <div key={index}>
        <ListItem button id={item.modalName} style={{ backgroundColor: { item.iconBackground } }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <{item.icon} onClick={this.openModal({ item.modalName })} style={{ color: { item.iconColor } }} />,
            </ListItemIcon>,
        </ListItem>
    </div>
)
```

I can then call the constant `{displayButtons}` as part of my `return`. However, this approach currently isn't working.

My code won't compile because there are various parsing errors when return properties from the Array - e.g. item.iconBackground.

What I'm trying to achieve would look like the following for the first object in the Array:

```
    <div key=0>
        <ListItem button id='dashboard' style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <DashboardIcon onClick={this.openModal('dashboard')} style={{ color: 'black' }} />,
            </ListItemIcon>,
        </ListItem>
    </div>
```

How can I amend my constant to return what I'm after?

Comment: Define "struggling to get this to work." What isn't working? Describe the (various) failure(s).

Comment: See the "Choosing the type at runtime" suggestions from React's docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime

Comment: I've updated my questions to be more precise with my "struggles"!

Comment: @Ross - thank you, so instead of using `{item.icon}` I need to declare a capitalised variable and use that - i.e. `const DisplayModalType = item.icon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to "unpack" the nested react component into a local variable that has the correct react component name casing, i.e. PascalCase.

```
const displayButtons = this.state.activeModal.map((item, index) => {
  const Icon = item.icon; // <-- create local variable with proper react component casing

  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <ListItem button id={item.modalName} style={{ backgroundColor: { item.iconBackground } }}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Icon // <-- use local "Component"
            onClick={this.openModal({ item.modalName })}
            style={{ color: { item.iconColor } }}
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>
    </div>
  );
})
```

You will likely need to do the same with the `item.modalName` that is passed to the `this.openModal` callback handler.